# como executar uma procedure com parametro em php

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso executar uma procedure enviando uma parâmetro pelo php mais não está retornando segue o código abaixo:

```
//código em PHP
$figura =  mysqli_query($conexao,"CALL `spare_change`.`boxlabel`('".$template."')") or die("erro no update");

//A Procedure Criada
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `boxlabel`(template varchar(20))
BEGIN

-- update prom.label_template set label_tpl_content = replace(label_tpl_content, ' eJz', 'eJz') where label_tpl_name = @template;
select * from prom.label_template where label_tpl_name = @template;

END
```

onde está o erro no código?

Answer (score 0):

Podes correr uma query antes para definir uma variável para a procedure, e depois usar essa variável na chamada.

```
mysqli_query($conexao, "SET @template = '" . $template . "'");
$figura =  mysqli_query($conexao,"CALL `spare_change`.`boxlabel`(@template)") or die("erro no update");
```

Mas para além disso, na procedure em si, o `--` está a fazer com que o `update` seja apenas uma linha de comentário.

Experimenta remover o `--` do inicio desta linha, senão esse código não vai ser executado.

```
-- update prom.label_template set label_tpl_content = replace(label_tpl_content, ' eJz', 'eJz') where label_tpl_name = @template;
```

Comment: essa procedure executa um update com um where desse parâmetro mais o update retorna sem afetar as linhas e fora da procedure funciona

Comment: O update na procedure está comentado, `--` no inicio de um comando é um comentário.

Comment: sim no código está comentado mais o que eu estou executando não roda a procedure mais não altera as linhas

Comment: Já experimentaste remover o `--`?

Comment: sim já removi sim